# How to fix "Typo in declared prop type: title" in my React linter?

Tags: eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm currently using ESLint, Airbnb lint, and Prettier to control code styling. I'm getting an error in the `header.propTypes` title below. I've looked at the [documentation](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-typos.md) but I'm not understanding the solution. This is a React project.

The error is:

> Typo in declared prop type: title

What am I doing wrong here?

```
export default function Header(props) {
  const { title } = props;
  return (
    <Helmet>
      <title>{title}</title>
    </Helmet>
  );
}

Header.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.title.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 7):

The RHS is invalid, `PropTypes.title.isRequired`. You probably mean to have `PropTypes.string.isRequired`.